Why can docker not find my file when I run docker compose up
I have a Django application for the backend and a Vue application for the frontend. The app works 100% on my local machine. I am trying to dockerize the application so I can deploy it on a VPS just for someone to look at.
The front end starts up when I run docker compose up but the back end gives me the same error every time:
python3: can't open file '/app/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory


My directory structure is as follows:
back (directory)
... (django apps directories)
-- manage.py
-- Dockerfile
-- requirements.txt

front (directory)
... (vue directories)
-- Dockerfile
-- package.json
-- vite.config.js
-- index.html

Here is my Dockerfile for the backend:
FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . back

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]


Here is my Dockerfile for the front end:
FROM node:20-alpine3.17

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app/
RUN npm install 

COPY . front/

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev:docker"]


and here is my docker-compose.yml file:
version: "1.1"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:15-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
  back:
    build: ./back
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/back
    env_file: ./back/.env
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: on-failure
  front:
    build: ./front
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ../front/src:/front/src
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    command: npm run dev
    depends_on:
      - back

So I have two questions please:

Why am I getting the cannot find file error?
When I deploy the working Docker image on the VPS how do I make it available on port 80 so if I point my domain to the VPS that I will see the complete site?

Thanks for any help.

Your copy directive is like so COPY . back and the work directory is /app so your code will basically get copied to /app/back the command runs in /app so you're basically running the command from the wrong directory.

Update the command for backend service at compose file to this:
command: python3 back/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
Run docker compose up --build again.
Here is the reason.
COPY . back at Dockerfile for backend: This will copy the contents of the current directory into a directory named back within the /app directory (according to WORKDIR) in the Docker container. So, the directory would be /app/back.
command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 at compose file: This command assumes that the manage.py file is in the root directory of your application within the container. But, based on your configuration, the directory should be app/back.
Updating the command to this should work:
command: python3 back/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

I'd probably fix this in the Dockerfile, and delete the command: override from the Compose file.

Ok I understand but then COPY . . should also fix it, which it doesn't. Your solution also doesn't fix it and I get the same error.
